# Sudo-like remembrance of passwords for own scripts

Tags: bash, python, password

I have a script which requires a password for authenticating a web service. A single password for a pre-defined user will suffice, and the password should if possible be stored securely (not plain text).

Obviously I don't want to write the password in clear text in the script for security reasons, so I have the script ask me the password, but entering the password every single time is a drag.

So how can I make it so I don't have to enter the password every time I run the script (like `sudo`)?

The script in this particular case is Python, but I guess it's better to implement it as a generic solution in Bash, so it can be reused for different languages like PHP or Ruby.

Pseudo-code:

```
#!/bin/bash
pw = cache.load() or {
  pw = ask_user()
  cache.save(pw, 15min)
}
myscript.py pw
```

Comment: Do you only need to store a single password, or is it a password per service, per user?

Comment: Single user will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent your own password store. Use an existing one. The Linux world has mostly converged on [GNOME Keyring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring). [Seahorse](http://wiki.gnome.org/Seahorse) provides a convenient GUI for exploring and modifying the keyring and setting a master password. The keyring can be queried from the command line with the [`secret-tool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/secret-tool.1.html) utility.

```
secret-tool store --label='Foobar webservice' service foobar account bob
```

```
pw=$(secret-tool lookup service foobar account bob)
```

The password in the store doesn't expire automatically, but the permission to access the store can.

Comment: This is something along the lines I'm looking for! However, I'm on OS X, and Homebrew doesn't carry `secret-tool`. How do I do the same thing on OS X (which is BSD-based).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation and used (abused?) `gpg` with public/private key encryption. The nice thing is that on most systems things are set up so that the access restricting password for a particular key is kept for 5 or 10 minutes, so you only have to type the password once then can go keep on using it and on non-use it will expire, much like `sudo`

You can easily get the result into `bash` or `Python`  (subprocess.check_output()). For encryption, i.e. storing, a new password
you don't need even need to give the access restricting password.

I didn't use my usual public/private keypair for this, because I don't in general want to keep access to that pair available. I later found [`pass`](https://www.passwordstore.org/) works in much the same way, managing multiple password files, and moulded the python program I use on several off the same principles as that program uses.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash

newTS=`date +%s`

if test -r ~/.password
then
        . ~/.password
else
        TS=0
fi

if test `expr $newTS - $TS` -gt 900
then
        # outdated password record
        rm -f ~/.password

        printf "Please enter your password: "
        read password

        printf "export TS=$newTS\nexport password=$password\n" > ~/.password
fi


echo "using password: $password"
```

***Note:  The previous code will overwrite the file `~/.password` unless you rename it.***

Comment: Oh. I forgot to mention that the password should be stored a similar or identical vault like UNIX stores the sudo password. But maybe this isn't possible?

Comment: Everything is possible, but I don't see much benefit to it since it would be stored in your home directory.  That said, sudo doesn't store a password, it just keeps track of when your privilege expires.